# Unable to insert items into DDB table if the table has 30-40k items

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams, amazon-dynamodb-index

The purpose of the below code is to retrieves data from firebase and post duplicate check & split it would append the items to buffer. Once the buffer limit has reached 4 its would insert the items in the DDB table using batchWriter.

To confirm the above code runs fine if I use a new/empty Dynamodb table but after the inserted items goes upto 40K then not all the expected items gets inserted. I re-used an old table also but same strange behavior.

I wish to understand is this could be a code logic problem or something modification required in the AWS table side.?

Results post running the code:
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
The below code successfully entered 32 items into the new table.
But when I just changed the table name to old table (which already contains 60,485 items)  not a single data got inserted out of the 32. Code dint give any error nor
did cloudwatch showed any alerts. However, If i keep executing the code for a longer period of time where 150 rows should have been inserted, only one gets inserted.

The WCU and RCU is set ot 25 and also had changed it to On-Demand, but still same problem.

Code:
-=-=-

```
`# Define the DynamoDB tables
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='my-region')
table_bms = dynamodb.Table('MS_TR_MS')

# Buffer and counter initialization
buffers = {
    'ms_str_msg': [],

}
counter = 0
buffer_size = 4
received_values = {}


def save_to_db(tob_id, top_name, top_data):
    with open(log_file_path, 'a') as log_file:
        try:
            # Check for duplicate entry
            key = f'{tob_id}_{top_name}'
            value = top_data
            if key in received_values and received_values[key] == value:
                # print(f"Duplicate entry for {key}: {value}. Discarding.")
                return
            else:
                received_values[key] = value
                print(f"Adding entry: {key}: {value}")
                
            # Split & Append data to the buffer            
            if isinstance(top_data, str):
                topic_data = top_data.split(":")[0]
                string_array = top_data.split(",")
            else:                
                return
                
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error: {top_data} \n{e}')
            return
# checking number of items inserted fro buffer to DDB table
        if counter>=30:
            exit()

    #Updating items to single table
        if top_name == "ms_str_msg":
            if len(string_array) == 5:
                # table = table_ms.name
                print('Updating MS table')

            buffers[top_name].append({
                # 'UID': {'S': unique_constant_value},
                "timestamp": str(current_date_time),
                "date": str(current_date),
                "time": str(current_timestamp),
                "tob_id": str(tob_id),
                "voltage": str(string_array[0]),
                "current_amps": str(string_array[1]),
                "total_capacity": str(string_array[2]),
                "SOC": str(string_array[3]),
                "Battery Level": str(string_array[4])})

        # Check buffer size and update tables
        if len(buffers[top_name]) >= buffer_size:
            update_tables(top_name)

# using batch_writer to write items from buffer to table

def update_tables(top_name):
    global counter
    try:
        with table_bms.batch_writer() as writer:
            for item in buffers[topic_name]:
                writer.put_item(Item=item)
                counter = counter+1
        buffers[top_name] = []
        
        # Adding a counter to check number of rows inserting
        print(f"Counter is {counter}")
        if counter>=30:
            exit()
            
    except ClientError as err:
        print("Couldn't load data into table %s. Here's why: %s: %s")

if __name__ == "_
```

*main*_":
main()`

### Code: 2

def update_tables():
try:
eastern = dateutil.tz.gettz('US/Eastern')
with table_bms.batch_writer() as writer:
for i in range(30000):
msg = f"counter {i}"
writer.put_item(Item={"Time": datetime.datetime.now(tz=eastern).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %Z'), "Message": msg})

Comment: Just an update...I also created and ran another python script to just add 30k numbers with timestamp but the script completed inserting only 105 items. There were already 72K items in the table. Not sure whats causing this issue as it says DDB can store large amount of data....
        eastern = dateutil.tz.gettz('US/Eastern')
        with table_bms.batch_writer() as writer:
            for i in range(30000):
                msg = f"counter {i}"
                writer.put_item(Item={"Time": datetime.datetime.now(tz=eastern).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %Z'), "Message": msg}

Comment: I don't know if this is a real bug in your code or something missing in the snippet, but you seem to be using "rotob_id" as the key, but it's not defined anywhere. If this key value is not different in every write, you'll not be writing as many items as you expected.

Comment: I have updated the correct code which  is still giving the problem where not all data are getting updated in the DDB table. Another Example is Code 2:
The below code should enter more than 30K items in the DDB table dummy, but after running the same code 3-4 time and the table item count size reached more than 90K, its not updated the next set of all counter (30K+) as it should in the table. Neither is it giving any error

Comment: Please help and suggest on the query:

Comment: The above problem now stands corrected post making few changes. The timestamp I was using was not DDB standard and hence conversion and insertion was overlapping with the 90 input records per min. secondly instead of using batch writer, I used Transact_write_item to insert the records. Both these resolved my problem.